# ASIHTTPRequest equivalent for Android or any HTTP request manager/wrapper?

Tags: android, web-services, http, libraries

I'm developing an app that will make extensive HTTP requests.

I know for a fact that iOS has a third-party library called ASIHTTPRequest to manage and organize all these requests, making it much easier and less tedious.

Is there a similar library available for Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/best-practices-for-accessing-google-apis-on-android.html) talk, if you're targeting pre-Gingerbread versions (<2.3) you should stick to [Apache Http Client library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html). If however you're targeting Gingerbread or later, you will be safer to use the [java.net.URLConneciton](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) class as recommended by the Google engineer.

Answer (score 6):

Use https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http
Just like ASIHTTPRequest, this lib makes is easy to make async requests without worrying about threads or async tasks.
It even includes a JSON parser.

You can also use http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI which looks good

Update : Android has released which does exactly what you want :
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-volley-library-example.html