# Android: Is there any similar library in Android like ASIHTTP library for iPhone?

Tags: android

Is there any similar library in Android like ASIHTTP library for iPhone?
I am looking for making asynchronous requests using queues. How can i achieve similar functionality in Android?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560762/asihttprequest-equivalent-for-android-or-any-http-request-manager-wrapper